# Display all search results

Tags: posts, search, options

Is there a way to display all the search results on the `search.php`?
Actually it is displaying only 10 results (as set in `WordPress settings > general`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do it would be to use `query_posts` again, doubling the number of database calls.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=999'); ?>
```

Better would be to add this to `functions.php`, altering the original query before it is executed:

```
function change_wp_search_size($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) // Make sure it is a search page
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 10; // Change 10 to the number of posts you would like to show

    return $query; // Return our modified query variables
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size'); // Hook our custom function onto the request filter
```

If you want to show an unlimited amount of posts, use `-1`.

Comment: `showposts` is depreciated, use `posts_per_page`. In any case the first example will not work - it will ignore the search term and just show the latest 999 posts. You would need to merge it with the current query (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)). The second answer is by far the best, and as @WouterB points out, avoids re-querying the database.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Harris, I copy pasted the first example from a very old blog, and then indeed realized that on a newer website I used the second option. Didn't look into the details.

Comment: Thanks Wouter it works! I also use this code to display number of results `global $wp_query;
$total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
echo $total_results;` and now is always displaying 0.

Comment: Please don't suggest `query_posts()` even as a "quick and dirty" solution.

Comment: To show *all* posts, as referenced in the question, you can change 10 to -1 `$query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = -1;`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy: `-1` overrides the limit. Just merge the default query with your custom arguments.

```
global $wp_query;
query_posts( 
    wp_parse_args(
         $wp_query->query
        ,array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks kaiser, I prefer the other method without doubling the queries. Anyway, this would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-limits/ You can set independent post limits/numbers for all kinds of results, i.e. search, category, tag, archives, author, paged, etc., without needing page templates or custom loops.

Comment: This time I prefer to get the result without a plugin. However, I had already used the one you suggested and it's very useful to customize search results.